# How to download a wordpress site from ManageWP and run locally

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I'm using XAMPP to run wordpress locally. I've downloaded a wordpress backup from ManageWP, I've set up the database using the sql file that comes in it and extracted all the files into /htdocs folder inside of the xampp directory.

When I access localhost/wordpress I get to see actual page but when I try to get to the dashboard by accessing localhost/wordpress/wp-admin I get redirected to the client's worpress login page.

So, I guess my question is, how can I download a backup file and run it locally?

Thank you!

If I install wordpress from the scratch, it works perfect. But I'm trying to run a client's wordpress website on my computer to make some changes on it.